# How to get a new ChildByAutoID from the FIrebase REST API without writing any actual data

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Swift, I can do the following using the Firebase API to obtain a new ID generated by Firebase:

```
let newListingRef = self.ref!.child("listings").child(location).childByAutoId()

let newBookId = newListingRef.key
```

I then use this ID to create a filename for an image I upload to Firebase Storage.

I am trying to do the same using the REST API, I know how to upload data to a given location using a POST request, but is there a way to replicate the above behaviour using the REST API?

UPDATE:

```
        let location = locationTextField.Text
        let url = "https://proj_id.firebaseio.com/listings/"
        let random = "grjirjgrirj"
        let postfix = ".json"
        let slash = "/"
        let strings = [url;location;slash;random;postfix]
        let url = System.String.Concat(strings)
        let req = WebRequest.Create(Uri(url)) 
        req.Method <- "POST"
        req.ContentLength <- int64(0)
        req.ContentType <- "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        let reqStream = req.GetRequestStream() 
        reqStream.Close()
        use resp = req.GetResponse() 
        use stream = resp.GetResponseStream() 
        use reader = new IO.StreamReader(stream)
```

The resulting URL is the following:

```
https://proj_id.firebaseio.com/listings/London/grjirjgrirj.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a push ID (how it's more commonly known in other Firebase SDKs) with no data behind it, perform the POST with an empty object at a location that is known not to exist:

```
curl -X POST -d '{}' 'https://your-project.firebaseio.com/definitely/doesnt/exist.json'
```

It will make no changes to your database, and will return you a push ID in the JSON response, which you can later use to add actual data.

Comment: so when I do this I obtain a null response...not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please see edit to the question. I also obtain this error `{System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00052] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/System/…}`

Comment: any suggestions @Doug?

Comment: I dunno, the curl command works just fine for me.  Does it work well for you?  It looks like you're using some other library to make an http request, but you haven't showed the code or said anything about it.

Comment: Hi Doug, I'm using F#, but if you could show me how to replicate this request using something like https://www.hurl.it/ I would be able to implement this in F#. I tried to send a request using hurl.it with no data, however, this fails with Bad Request 400: `"error": "No data supplied."`

Comment: I've never used F#.  I suggest you write another question explaining what you're trying to do, and be specific about the code you're writing.  The POST I gave you definitely works, you just need to figure out to translate that to code.

Comment: could you please translate that curl command into a POST request like the one in the screenshot posted above, or alternatively tell me how to set it up on hurl.it and I can proceed from there. F# isn't the issue here, I know how to translate a POST request into F#, however I am not that familiar with curl and it would be much more helpful if you translated that curl command for me into something like a request on hurl.

Comment: The body of the request is `{}`.  Everything else should be obvious.